# SparkR: Join two dataframes on multiple join conditions

Tags: join, sparkr

SparkR version 1.4.1

Am trying to join two dataframes df1 and df2 on two join conditions like this:

```
df3 <- join(df1, df2, df1$col1==df2$col2 && df1$col3==df2$col4)
```

However, this fails with this error:
**invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'**

Join on single condition works fine.

Answer (score 7):

It's just a slight change of interface: use singel & instead of double:

```
df3 <- join(df1, df2, df1$col1==df2$col2 & df1$col3==df2$col4)
```